# Is Sideshow Bob out of tune when performing Englishman?

Tags: voice

In the chapter [Cape Feare](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0701080/) from The Simpsons, the Sideshow Bob character sings a couple of excerpts from the [H.M.S. Pinafore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.M.S._Pinafore) opera.

In the last bit he performs "Englishman", you can hear it [here](https://youtu.be/huX8Ta3-vTA?t=3m22s). With my brother we have an argument about that and perhaps someone here could help us resolve it.

Is Sideshow Bob out of tune when he hits the last high I (min 3:43 in the video linked above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like Kelsey Grammer's falsetto was aiming for that high A4 but landed instead on the Bb above it. He quickly corrects himself of it, though, by shifting down to the intended A.